# Is the function $f$ continuous at $(0,0)$?

Tags: limits, continuity

Does $f$ have a limit as $(x,y)$ tend to $(0,0)$? If yes calculate the limit.

$$f(x, y) := \dfrac{1−\cos (xy)}{xy^2}$$

[ Hint: consider the variable $t := xy$ ]

So first I showed that the function is not continuous at $(0,0)$ by finding that $|f(x,y)| \le \frac{1}{|x|}$. Hence, it has a limit as $(x,y)$ tend to $(0,0)$

But I'm finding trouble calculating its limit as $(x,y)$ tend to $(0,0)$. Any help finding the limit please? Thank you

Comment: Use the Taylor series expansion of cosine. You should get $f(x,y)\sim\frac12x\to0$.

Comment: The comment by @PeterForeman is correct.  To see the relevance of the hint about $t=xy$, notice that $f(x,y)=x\frac{1-\cos t}{t^2}$ and that $\lim_{t\to0}\frac{1-\cos t}{t^2}=\frac12$.